# Count of matched groups in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex, regex-group

If I have a regex with a bunch of groups (using parentheses), some of which are optional (using question marks), how do I find the number of groups that were matched by the regex?  I know Python has a function called groups() which will tell you, but how do you do it in Ruby?

```
m = /\d{2}(:\d{2}(:\d{2})?)?/.match('10') # I want to return 1
m = /\d{2}(:\d{2}(:\d{2})?)?/.match('10:30') # I want to return 2
m = /\d{2}(:\d{2}(:\d{2})?)?/.match('10:30:20') # I want to return 3
```

Comment: The `match` method returns a MatchData object, which has a `length` method available https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/MatchData.html

Comment: Actually, what you're probably looking for is the `captures` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MatchData has a `#size` and `#length` method, but they will count empty groups as well and returning result will `3` in all three cases.

So it seems that the only solution is something like the following

```
/\d{2}(:\d{2}(:\d{2})?)?/.match('10').to_a.compact.count
```

Comment: You can use `compact` to eliminate `nil`s.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array#compact` like so:

```
/\d{2}(:\d{2}(:\d{2})?)?/.match('10').to_a.compact
```